# code a number into letters

Tags: php, javascript

Lets say I have something like 97463

I want to code it into letters say kljhs

I'm using php/javascript at the moment, but I guess its a universal problem.

Whats the most efficient way to do this in a way thats reversible?

(reversible meaning given numbers I can make the letter code and then later given just the number code I can return the letters)

Comment: By what logic do you want to do the encoding? A=1, B=2...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the strtr function

```
$input = '123456';
$output = strtr($input, '0123456789', 'abcdefghij');
```

To reverse, use

```
$input = 'bcdefg';
$output = strtr($input, 'abcdefghij', '0123456789');
```

http://codepad.org/6hGqJPD6

Comment: The opther solution is faster, but this gives more control.  I like!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dechex](http://php.net/dechex)() to encode the number as hexadecimal, and [hexdec](http://php.net/hexdec)() to reverse:

```
$hex = dechex(97463); // "17cb7"
$dec = hexdec($hex);  // 97463
```

Alternatively you may want to use [base_convert](http://php.net/base_convert)(), to convert to an arbitrary base from 2 to 36 :

```
$enc = base_convert(97463, 10, 36);  // "237b"
$dec = base_convert("237b", 36, 10); // 97463
```